# Mapbox: How do I get the duration values of travel between points from an http request link?

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have been having trouble on putting the duration values of travel between points from the http request link to a variable, using Mapbox and javascript. The http request for Mapbox Matrix API link works fine and is found in the inspect element and displays the matrix of durations and distances properly when opened but I can't get the javascript to put it in a variable.

note: when the HTML file is opened, an initial marker is set on the current position. Click on any part of the map to place another marker then click on the initial marker to finish the plotting. You should have plots on the map including the initial marker and an http request link on the inspect element console. I have just started doing javascript a few days ago and I am almost clueless with javascript and Mapbox APIs so it would be of a great help if someone could find a way for it to store the durations in a variable

My html and javascript are as follows:

HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' dir="ltr">
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    

    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    
    
    
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <style>
    #map {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    body{
        margin: 0;
    }
    .mapboxgl-marker {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        z-index: 5;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #305bad;
    }
    .mapbox-marker:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT FILE

````
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYXJjZWxkaXpvbiIsImEiOiJja3BvemlnajIwbGMzMm9wYXdsZWtlYzhxIn0.B1rc7bpub0gGq6q3xpIhvw';


navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successLocation, errorLocation, {enableHighAccuracy: true})

let coordinates = 0;
function successLocation(position){
    setupMap([position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude])
}

function errorLocation(){
    setupMap([120.9816438, 14.58925259])
}


//creation of map
function setupMap(center){
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: center,
        zoom: 16
    });
    

    //creation of navigation object
    const nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
    map.addControl(nav);
    
    var start = center;
    console.log(start);

    //initialization of the url
    var url = "https://api.mapbox.com/directions-matrix/v1/mapbox/driving/" + center;
    
    var coords = center;
    
    //creation of initial marker
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.id = 'startMarker';
    
    var startMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(center)
    .addTo(map);
    
    //creation of marker on click event
    var markerCount = 1;
    map.on('click', function(e){
        url = getLocations(url, map, e);
        
        var coords = center;
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.id = 'marker' + markerCount;
        markerCount++;
        
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .addTo(map);
    });
    
    
    //when initial marker is clicked, url string is concatenated with my mapbox key in finishURL
    //the URL is then passed to requestMatrix, where the http request is made
    startMarker.getElement().addEventListener('click', () => {
        url = finishURL(url, map);
        requestMatrix(url);
    });
    
}

//list the coordinates of the recently placed marker on the url string
function getLocations(link, map, e){
    var url = link + ";" + e.lngLat.lng + "," + e.lngLat.lat;
    return url;
}

//where the url is concatenated with my mapbox key
function finishURL(link, map){
    var url = link +  "?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYXJjZWxkaXpvbiIsImEiOiJja3BvemlnajIwbGMzMm9wYXdsZWtlYzhxIn0.B1rc7bpub0gGq6q3xpIhvw";
    return url;
}

//where the url is passed onto to be requested 
function requestMatrix(link){
    var url = link;
    console.log("passed: " + url);
    //the URL works fine, and can be opened to view the distance and duration values
    


    //starting from this part, I have just copied it from a youtube video, it seemed like it would work but it won't
    //https://youtu.be/7vnVpw1o0zY?t=559
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.responseType = 'json';
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.onload = function(){
        var jsonResponse = req.response;
        var duration = jsonResponse.durations[0][1]/60;
        console.log("durations: " + duration); //at this point, durations should be
        //displayed in the console, but it doesn't
        }
    }

    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out after a few minutes of posting this, sorry! haha
I've placed a

```
req.send(null);
```

right after the

```
req.open('GET', url, true);
```

still, would anybody care to explain why it wouldn't work without it? :) thank you